# How to make picture srcset with media queries in liquid (shopify)

Tags: image, shopify, liquid, responsive-images, srcset

I'm looking to render device specific images for both my products, but also all the content that is uploaded through the customize section in Shopify.

I'm looking to generate something like the following:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1028px)" srcset="path/image-desktop.jpg 1x, path/image-desktop@2x.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"  srcset="path/image-tablet.jpg 1x, path/image-tablet@2x.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(max-width: 768px)"  srcset="path/image-mobile.jpg 1x, path/image-mobile@2x.jpg 2x">
    <img src="path/image.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

How can this be done in liquid as a reusable snippet for both product images, collection images and for uploaded images in the customise section? I'm not looking to use a js library to handle it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what have tried on your own?

Comment: This is what I have right now which is not working. It's as expect showing the correct images between the different sizes https://gist.github.com/martinsoender/c4ef64007856dc9d545706246dc7ea3c